# Operator+ overloading is not working

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I just developed a String class and overloaded =, <<, [] operators but my operator+ is not working, a little help with it please!

Class:

```
class String
{
private:
    int length;
    char *chars;
public:
    String oprator+(String &obj);
}
```

Main Code:

```
int main ( )
{
    String str1;
    str1 = "This is first text";
    String str2;
    str2 = "This is second text";

    String bigString = str1 + str2;
    bigString = bigString + "This is third text";
}
```

operator+ overload:

```
String::String operator+ (String &obj)
{
    String *temp = new String();
    strcpy(temp->chars, chars);
    strcat(temp->chars, obj.chars);
    return *temp;
}
```

Comment: Does it really say `oprator` in your code?

Comment: Are you going to answer the question? Is the `oprator` typo in the real code, or just a copying error? I suspect it's just a copying error, because the code won't even compile with the typo.

Comment: You're returning a copy of the `new`ed string and thus leaking the `new`ed string.

Comment: `temp->chars` is never initialised (or allocated) in the code you've shown, so there's no way this can work.

Comment: @JonathanPotter ; Then how to actually overload operator+ for the given code??

Comment: You do `strcpy(temp->chars`, but `temp->chars` is an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `new` in the operator. All if gives you is a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

Your `operator+` should read

```
class String
{
private:
    int length;
    char *chars;
    String(const char* s, size_t n):
        length( n ),
        chars( new char[n] )
    {
        std::copy(s, s+length, chars);
    }

public:
    explicit String(size_t l):
        length(l),
        chars( new char[l] )
    {
    }

    String(char const* s):
        String(s, strlen(s) )
    {
    }

    String(String const& s):
        String(s.chars, s.length)
    {
    }

    String& operator=(String s)
    {
        std::swap(chars, s.chars);
        std::swap(length, s.length);
        return *this;   
    }

    ~String() {delete[] chars;}

    template<size_t N> String(const char s[N]):
        String(s, N)
    {
    }

    void append(String const& s)
    {
        char* tmp = new char[length + s.length];
        std::copy(chars, chars+length, tmp);
        std::copy(s.chars, s.chars + s.length, tmp + length);
        delete[] chars;
        chars = tmp;
    }

    template<typename S> friend S& operator<<(S&, String const&);
};

String operator+(String const& s1, String const& s2)
{
    String merged(s1);
    merged.append(s2);
    return merged;
}

template<typename S> S& operator<<(S& stream, String const& s)
{
    return stream << s.chars;
}

int main()
{
  String s("bla");
  std::cout << s << std::endl;
  String s2 = s + "bla";
  std::cout << s2 << std::endl;
}
```

You don't want to modify the argument, so it should be a const reference. Making it non-const prevents code like

```
bigString = bigString + "This is third text";
```

because the create temporary String, if you add a non-explicit constructor, cannot bind to an l-value reference.

And the operator should not be a member function, but a free function to take advantage of conversions on the first argument. With a free function, you can do

```
bigString = "This is third text" + bigString;
```

which is not possible with the member function because `char const[]` does not have an `operator+` which takes a `String`.

PS: You may want to read [Monoliths "Unstrung"](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm) for some critic of std::string's interface.

Comment: That article says resize can be implemented as a non-member non-friend without loss of efficiency. But I disagree.

Comment: @jens You missed the memory leak.

Comment: @juanchopanza I've changed the example to a complete implementation.

Comment: @NeilKirk Could you elaborate why? I looked at 21.4.4/8 which defines the semantics of `resize`, and I think it cannot be faster. But even if resize cannot be implemented as a non-friend free function, the main point of the article still holds.

Comment: `resize` won't allocate dynamic memory if the new size is below the capacity. But they are creating a temporary string object, which will allocate new memory.

Comment: @NeilKirk I also thought so, but the standard says "replaces the string designated by *this with a string of length n whose elements are a copy of the initial elements". I guess this makes a copy mandatory, but I am pretty sure that the STL implementations don't do this.

Comment: That doesn't preclude placing the new string on the same memory buffer.

Comment: @NeilKirk I don't know. I would expect to have something two times when I create a copy of it, so using the same buffer would contradict that. But then, copying would be a useless operation because the string is only owner of the buffer, so the original buffer would be released anyway and nobody could have access. The usual reading seems to be different and match the expectation, at least libstdc++ implements it that way. Maybe the copy is a legacy wording from times when copy-on-write was the usual implementation?